# Porting from Glib to Qt

Tags: c++, qt, glib, qtcore, qfileinfo

I am porting an application from Glib to Qt.

I do have a lot of API specific to Gtk, but it's difficult to find the equivalent variants in Qt. I am looking for the alternative of these:

- g_path_get_basename
- g_path_get_dirname
- strdup

Any idea?

Comment: In case exact equivalence is needed, or if you just suspect exact equivalence is needed, I'd suggest writing helper functions, which have exactly same behavior as these GTK functions (the helper functions would still probably use `QString` instead of whatever GTK-preferred string type).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There really are not direct equivalences for these, but this is the closest that you get:

## g_path_get_basename

> [QString QFileInfo::fileName() const](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qfileinfo.html#fileName)
>
> Returns the name of the file, excluding the path.

*Note*: do not get tempted by the similarly called [baseName()](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qfileinfo.html#baseName) and [completeBaseName()](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qfileinfo.html#completeBaseName) in Qt as they are *not* the same. The Qt and Glib developers decided to use different terms for the same things.

Also, even this is not the same because it will not behave the same way for empty file names or those which end with a slash.

## g_path_get_dirname

> [QString QFileInfo::path() const](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qfileinfo.html#path)
>
> Returns the file's path. This doesn't include the file name.
>
> Note that, if this QFileInfo object is given a path ending in a slash, the name of the file is considered empty and this function will return the entire path.

*Note*: [absolutePath()](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qfileinfo.html#absolutePath) or [canonicalPath()](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qfileinfo.html#canonicalPath) will not work because they will return absolute paths, whereas the glib variant returns relative paths.

## strdup

Just use `std::string`, `std::array` or `QByteArray`. Do not get tempted that `QString` would be the same. It simply is not because that would have the UTF overhead, too, among other things.

Here is some code to print these out:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QByteArray>

#include <iostream>

#include <glib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char filePath[] = "tmp/foo.bar.baz";
    qDebug() << "=========== Glib ===============\n";
    cout << "Base name: " << g_path_get_basename(filePath) << endl;
    cout << "Directory name: " << g_path_get_dirname(filePath) << endl;
    cout << "String dup: " << strdup(filePath) << endl;
    qDebug() << "\n=========== Qt =================\n";
    QFileInfo fileInfo(filePath);
    qDebug() << "File name:" << fileInfo.fileName();
    qDebug() << "Directory name:" << fileInfo.path();
    qDebug() << "String dup:" << QByteArray("foo.bar.baz");
    return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core
SOURCES += main.cpp
packagesExist(glib-2.0) {
    CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
    PKGCONFIG += glib-2.0
}
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

#### Output

```
=========== Glib ===============

Base name: foo.bar.baz
Directory name: tmp
String dup: tmp/foo.bar.baz

=========== Qt =================

File name: "foo.bar.baz"
Directory name: "tmp"
String dup: "foo.bar.baz"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use QFileInfo for the following:

`g_path_get_basename` => `QFileInfo::baseName` or `QFileInfo::completeBaseName`

`g_path_get_dirname`  => `QFileInfo::path`

`strdup` is not needed. Simply use `QString` allocated on the stack in most cases. Qt API take QString.

Comment: The first two suggestions are wrong and I think the fourth, too. Have you tested these yourself? It is really strange people upvote incorrect answers!